# Website for personal usage

Tags: language-agnostic

I want to setup a simple site and I don't have any web development experience.
For a start, I need to create a basic form where I can post text and store it in a database. Nothing fancy.

Questions that I need answers:

- Good free web hosting sites?
- Any frameworks that I should use? (I'm familiar with Python and C++).
- Are there websites where users can store and search any type of data?

Note that it's for **personal usage** and that I use Windows XP.

(*I don't have any web development experience*: I know HTML, how to use CSS, and I've tried Javascript, but I didn't build any *real* site)

I'd really like your help on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're familiar with Python I'd suggest using the [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/). It's free if you don't have a lot of traffic and the framework provided there is also very easy to use.

Comment: +1 AppEngine offers a complete solution, cleaner and simpler than more classic hosting (in particular if you want to use Python, where other free hosting solutions I'm aware of only offer CGI, which may be confusing to setup at first)

Comment: Java support is coming to App Engine too.  In fact it's JVM support so you can use other languages that run on the JVM such as JRuby.

Answer (score 4):

If you just need a form and storage, then the absolute simplest solution (no coding required) would be a [Google Docs spreadsheet form](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=87809).

Comment: Not bad for a start. It's very convenient. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're only storing text with no need for intelligent queries, you could also consider using a wiki. I have my personal site hosted by wikidot.com which is free and perfect for my needs (I use it to store all my links with comments and some reviews).

Regards,

Sebastiaan

Comment: Thanks Sebastiaan. It seems great for keeping (organizing) notes. I just registered! The search engine doesn't look good (maybe I'm wrong), otherwise it'd be superb.